# Why does my Eevee camera view look different to the render?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am new"ish" to blender and I am trying to work out why the camera view looks so different to the actual render. I want to render to look like the camera view. This is the render. You can see the clouds are pushed down and look and cover the moon. I want my render to look like the camera view in the first image.

[image: This is the view from the camera before I render.]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xICJE.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/xICJE.jpg

[image: This is the render. You can see the clouds are pushed down and look and cover the moon. I want my render to look like the camera view in the first image.]

[image]

Comment: BTW the reason one was shifted from  the other was that their (identical) materials were being mapped in the Generated space of their respective objects.  Collider is a combo of dome and moon, Sphere isn't. They have different bounding boxes, which are the XYZ 0-1 bases of their Generated texture spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two objects in your scene with the clouds texture, "COLLIDER" and "Sphere". The second is the one that shows the moon, the first one is obscuring the moon:

[image: two cloud objects]

The reason it doesn't show up in the "3D Viewport" is that you set the *Viewport Display* in the  *Object Properties* to *Display As* > *Wire*, this way it will not show the texture in the viewport. Switch it to *Textured*.

[image: display as wire]

Comment: You're amazing thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped you, you might consider accepting the answer: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)